# What software will run the new Windows 8 in virtualization under OS X?

Tags: macos, windows-8, virtualization

I've read a lot about the new Windows OS, but would like to run it first hand. I've got several Macs with Mountain Lion (10.8) and presume I can use [this evaluation license](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) to test the OS for my consulting company.

What else do I need to run Windows 8 in virtualization (as I'd rather not mess with BootCamp for several reasons)? Any other gotchas from someone who has gone down this path would be appreciated as well.

Comment: The latest versions of all major VMs for OSX (Parallels Desktop, vmware, virtualbox) supports Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a [hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor).

I have had the most experience with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) - it is easy to set up and it performs reasonably well. There are options for sharing folders between a guest and a host.

[image]

Comment: Downloading the OSX client for VirtualBox presently... Have you run the evaluation license on OS X or is this just a general plug for something you've run on other OS and presume it's solid on OS X as well?

Comment: This did the trick. For someone like me that't totally new to Windows 8 - everything went well installing the developer evaluation release on top of a "leave all the defaults in place" virtual box for Win8. The only counter-intuitive step was you should pick the non-default install since the Win8 installer [insists on rebooting](http://cl.ly/KUPt) to try to run a migration rather than just installing onto the blank drive image.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox, although it runs best if you set up the VM as a Windows 7 device and then install Windows 8.

Why? I don't know, it just does!